# Translate Model.each to an SQL statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I translate the order Active Record displays `@vehicles.each do |vehicle|` to an SQL `SELECT` statement?

I noticed that `@vehicles.each do |vehicle|` displays the results in a particular order, not the same order as `SELECT * FROM vehicles`

How do I find what order this is?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your question is very vague but perhaps `Vehicle.all(:select => "id, name", :conditions => ["id not in (?)", ids])`

Comment: A little bit mor description of your question.

Comment: Have you had a look in `log/development.log` to see what query it's actually executing to get that list `@vehicles`?

Comment: i asume @vehicles = Vehicles.all in your controller, you can specifiy the order you want your Items returned from the DB such as Vehicles.order("id desc") or Vehicles.order("id asc")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the executed SQL query by printing `@vehicles.to_sql` or by looking at the log file. The `each` enumeration method will not add any order statements itself.

Also, note that `select * from vehicles` does not imply any particular order. So it can be different even for the same query.